# Retrofit 2 returns null body

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2

I am trying to implement the basic exercise Retrofits shows : making simple get queries to the github API. I am trying to get a list of Repository, but though the result's status is 200, the body is null.
There is some tickets on github complaining about the same problem, and it looks like it may come from the json converter. I use gson. But I fail to discover which code is the culprit ...

Here are my dependencies :

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

The repository POJO :

```
public class Repository {
private int id;
private String name;
private String full_name;
private String html_url;

// getters + setters + toString
```

}

The client interface :

```
public interface GithubClient {
public static final String ENDPOINT = "https://api.github.com";

@GET("/users/{user}/repos")
Call<List<Repository>> getByUser(@Path("user") String user);

@GET("/search/repositories")
Call<List<Repository>> getByKeywords(@Query("q") String q);
```

}

How it is initialized :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(GithubClient.ENDPOINT)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
githubClient = retrofit.create(GithubClient.class);
```

And the request execution :

```
Call<List<Repository>> request = githubClient.getByUser(inputText);
        request.enqueue(new Callback<List<Repository>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Repository>> call, Response<List<Repository>> response) {
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                results.setText(response.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Repository>> call, Throwable t) {
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                results.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Comment: did you try using annotations @Expose and @SerializedName("field_name") on your POJO

Comment: are you using github v3 apis? Everting looks good from your end

Answer (score 0):

I visited https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=threetenabp in my browser, and I see a different JSON structure than it seems you're expecting:

> ```
> {
>   "total_count": 4,
>   "incomplete_results": false,
>   "items": [
>     {
>       "id": 38503932,
>       "name": "ThreeTenABP",
>       ...
>     },
>     {
>       "id": 61799973,
>       "name": "ThreeTenABPSample",
>       ...
>     },
>     {
>       "id": 78114982,
>       "name": "TwitterPack",
>       ...
>     },
>     {
>       "id": 76958361,
>       "name": "ZonedDateTimeProguardBug",
>       ...
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

In your code, I see this call:

```
@GET("/search/repositories")
Call<List<Repository>> getByKeywords(@Query("q") String q);
```

This would work if the JSON response received were structured like this:

```
[
  { "id": ... },
  { "id": ... }
]
```

In other words, in the real JSON response, the `"items"` field is what you would call a `List<Repository>`, but you need something to represent the top-level response object.

I would create a new class like this one:

```
public class GithubResponse {

    private int total_count;
    private boolean incomplete_results;
    private List<Repository> items;
}
```

And then I would change the call in your client interface to this:

```
@GET("/search/repositories")
Call<GithubResponse> getByKeywords(@Query("q") String q);
```

Comment: Thank you it corrected the "get by keyword" part. But the "get by user name" part still returns an null body. And when I test https://api.github.com/users/test/repos it returns directly an array. So I don't see where the error is for this one ...